# MySQL 5.6: Slave_IO thread stops working while replicating

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

Standard replication breaks for no apparent reason.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@version, @@version_comment;
+----------------+-------------------+
| @@version      | @@version_comment |
+----------------+-------------------+
| 5.5.52-MariaDB | MariaDB Server    |
+----------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

slave is running fine.

```
# mysql -e "SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" | grep "Slave"
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it



Id  | User        | Host                        | db       | Command | Time | State                                                                       | Info             | Progress |
+-----+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+----------+
|   1 | system user |                             | NULL     | Connect |  438 | Waiting for master to send event                                            | NULL             |    0.000 |
|   2 | system user |                             | NULL     | Connect |  120 | Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it | NULL             |    0.000 |
|   3 | u271869     | S0280I2.ba.ad.ssa.gov:59117 | mysql    | Sleep   |    2 |                                                                             | NULL             |    0.000 |
|   4 | nagiosxi    | localhost                   | nagiosxi | Sleep   |  176 |                                                                             | NULL             |    0.000 |


mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: $IP
                  Master_User: repluser
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000007
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 433
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay.000265
                Relay_Log_Pos: 283
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000007
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 433
              Relay_Log_Space: 710
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
           Master_SSL_CA_File: /etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: /etc/mysql/client-cert.pem
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: /etc/mysql/client-key.pem
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1124732721
                  Master_UUID: 4412a455-e1d0-11e3-835a-5254007fe78d
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: /etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql replication
shareedit
edited Jul 18 '14 at 13:16
```

Comment: What is the value of `log_slave_updates`?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, what is making you think replication breaks? Is there any active writes being made to the master? If you did `show master status\G` on the master, as well as `show processlist;` are you seeing any active queries or any queries that are locked?

If you posted some of the binlog or taken a look at it, it may help you see, if replication is being broken, what exact query is breaking it. You can access the binlog by doing
`mysqlbinlog binlog.file`

For more [reference on binlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html)

Comment: when i make changes in master it doesn't get reflected on to the slave,

Comment: when i make changes in master it doesn't get reflected on to the slave, i din't see any error thats breaking replication. when i run mysqlbinlog mariadb-relay-bin.000002 | grep error_code=1 to see any errors , i didn't find any